# SharePoint 2010 not seeing Active Directory users

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, sharepoint

I'm pretty new to Active Directory and SharePoint but I was given to understand they are supposed to play well together.

Now I have successfully set up AD with multiple user accounts that work on any member computer. I have also successfully installed SharePoint 2010 Server on an AD machine. 
Both the AD server and SharePoint servers are on separate machines (VMs running on ESXi to be precise).

I can only log on with user accounts I create on the local server. Furthermore the user browser thing for adding users will only see local users.

I've followed the advice here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262350.aspx#section2 for Classic authentication and also NTLM claims based authentication but to no avail.

Is there something fundamental I am getting wrong here? I'd be really thankful for any help you can lend me; I've been googling and scratching my head for a couple of days now.

P

Comment: This is actually my question, I just had a fumble at logging in for a moment.

Comment: You may want to take a look on the sharepoint Q&A site: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Go to Central Administration -> Service Applications and synchronize the User Profile service with Active Directory

More information can be found here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721049.aspx

Edit:
Here is a better step by step guide to enabling it to work with AD
http://www.jppinto.com/2011/04/configure-active-directory-ad-synchronization-for-sharepoint-2010/